# How to delete a character object in a simple vector in R

Tags: r

Take a long vector of names like this: names <- c("Bob", "Alice", "Ted"....) Assume there are 100 names. How can I delete just one name out of the list without knowing it's position?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `setdiff`

```
names <- setdiff(names, "Alice")
```

Or use `!=`

```
names <- names[names!="Alice"]
```

Comment: I tried posting a `grepl` solution and you beat me to it, as always. :) `names[!grepl("Alice", names)]`

Comment: Thank you! This was my first time posting a question on SO, nice to see this website really works!!!